# RecyclerView Items' values reset when scrolling down

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Here is the scenario of what I am trying to do: I am creating a RecyclerView that can add or remove one or more child item/fragment/view that has EditText(s) but....

Here is my problem: Whenever I scroll down in my RecyclerView, its items' value resets. I think the problem here is that the RecyclerView Adapter cannot bind or hold the values but I don't know where exactly is the problem in my code.

```
class StocksAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {


class StockFragmentHolder : ViewHolder {
    fun Double.format(digits: Int) = java.lang.String.format("%,.${digits}f", this)


    lateinit var numberOfShares: EditText;
    lateinit var buyPrice: EditText;
    lateinit var btnCompute: Button
    lateinit var btnRemove: Button
    lateinit var stockAveragePrice: TextView
    lateinit var stockTotalAmount: TextView
    private var savedStock : Stock? = null

    constructor(view: View) : super(view) {
        numberOfShares = view.findViewById(R.id.stockNumberOfShares)
        buyPrice = view.findViewById(R.id.stockBuyPrice)
        btnCompute = view.findViewById(R.id.btnCompute)
        btnRemove = view.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove)
        stockAveragePrice = view.findViewById(R.id.stockAveragePrice)
        stockTotalAmount = view.findViewById(R.id.stockTotalAmount)
    }


    fun populateView(stock: Stock, onStocksAdapterListener: OnStocksAdapterListener, position: Int) {

        if(savedStock == null || stock.buyPrice > 0 || stock.numberOfShares > 0) {
            savedStock = stock
        }

        this.buyPrice.setText(if (savedStock!!.buyPrice <= 0.0) "" else savedStock!!.buyPrice.toString())
        this.numberOfShares.setText(if (savedStock!!.numberOfShares <= 0.0) "" else savedStock!!.numberOfShares.toString())
        this.stockAveragePrice.text = "0"
        this.stockTotalAmount.text = "0"

        this.btnCompute.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

            var stock = Stock();

            stock.numberOfShares = this.numberOfShares.text.toString().toLongOrNull()
            stock.buyPrice = this.buyPrice?.text.toString().toDoubleOrNull()
            stock.sellPrice = 0.0


            if (stock.numberOfShares != null || stock.numberOfShares != 0L) {

                var buyTotalAmount: Double = 0.0;
                buyTotalAmount = StocksCalculator.calculateTotalSharesPrice(stock, StocksCalculator.TRANSACTION_FEE_BASE_VALUES, Constants.TRANSACTION_TYPE.TRANSACTION_TYPE_BUY)

                var averagePricePerShare = (buyTotalAmount / stock.numberOfShares)

                this.stockAveragePrice.text = averagePricePerShare.format(2);
                this.stockTotalAmount.text = "" + buyTotalAmount.format(2)

                onStocksAdapterListener.onStocksComputeButtonClicked(stock.numberOfShares, averagePricePerShare, buyTotalAmount, position)
            }
        })

        this.btnRemove.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            onStocksAdapterListener.onStocksRemoveButtonClicked(position)
        })

    }
}


lateinit var onStocksAdapterListener: OnStocksAdapterListener;
lateinit var listStocks: ArrayList<Stock>

public constructor(listStocks: ArrayList<Stock>, onStocksAdapterListener: OnStocksAdapterListener) : this() {
    this.listStocks = listStocks
    this.onStocksAdapterListener = onStocksAdapterListener
    setHasStableIds(true)

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    var itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_stock, parent, false)
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return position
}


override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return listStocks.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
    var stock: Stock = listStocks.get(position)
    holder.populateView(stock, this.onStocksAdapterListener, position)
}


public interface OnStocksAdapterListener {
    public fun onStocksAddButtonClicked()

    public fun onStocksComputeButtonClicked(numberOfShares: Long?, averagePricePerShare: Double?, averageTotalAmount: Double?, position: Int)

    public fun onStocksRemoveButtonClicked(position: Int)
}
```

Here is how I create my recyclerView in my Fragment:

```
    val mLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
    var recyclerView: RecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)

    val itemDecorator = DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)
    itemDecorator.setDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.divider))
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecorator)
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager)
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(DefaultItemAnimator())
    recyclerView.adapter = stocksAdapter
```

I have tried disabling the setIsRecyclable of the ViewHolder but the problem still persists.

What is the best approach to prevent the RecyclerView to stop resetting the values? Or should I replace the RecyclerView with ListView?

Comment: try removig the  if(savedStock == null || stock.buyPrice > 0 || stock.numberOfShares > 0) {
            savedStock = stock
        }
and only savedStock = stock

Comment: @SahilManchanda Hi, I have done that. The problem is still there :(

Comment: when you say it resets values what do you mean?

Comment: @Eminem the EditText values reset to default value of 0 when they should not be because I have already set there values to none 0. I think that is because the RecyclerView already destroyed the top most items thats why there values were reset

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a workaround by increasing the cache size of the recyclerview. Just ensure that the cache size is good enough for your application.

code:

```
recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(int);
```

Comment: but what if we have too many items?

Comment: in the adapter class this can look like eg: `@Override public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) { super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView); recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(200);}`

Answer (score 1):

As I have seen in your code you are trying to add an item just after the activity load. So when you scroll your activity then again it calls the onCreate activity and data is again load from the storage or network so load data in specific method or in OnActiviyt Result method.

Comment: Hi, I have initialized the data and the recycler in onCreateView of the fragment. I have figured out why the child items reset, because the recycler view have already recycled the previous items after adding new items.

I have found a workaround for this, increase the size of recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(int); to ensure that the recyclerview will not yet destroy the previous items

Comment: Just add an item in recyclerView after creating it or by using any method so that app cannot load data again automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in your code what is `savedStock` or what do you use it for. But your `populateView` method doesn't work as intended.

If you only use this `savedStock` for rendering, remove it completely, otherwise, don't use it in the `populateView`.

In `populateView` depend on the `stock` passed according to the position you get to draw the values.

Your code should be something like

```
this.buyPrice.setText(if (stock!!.buyPrice <= 0.0) "" else stock!!.buyPrice.toString())
this.numberOfShares.setText(if (stock!!.numberOfShares <= 0.0) "" else stock!!.numberOfShares.toString())
```