# Calculate int values of each recyclerview item and sum all together when activity finish

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am making a multiple choice app in which the questions are displayed in recyclerview with arraylist. And also the buttons to choose your answer. And get Right answers from sqlite and do if condition with the user input answers to calculate marks in each question. like this....

[image]

My problem is i have no idea how to calculate marks with the user input (clicked buttons bta1 true, bta1 false, etc....) when clicked finish button (that is in main activity).
i want to calculate marks in each question, total 5marks for each question. If i clicked finish button and if there is 10 questions and all user input answers are right, the total marks should be 50marks.

This is my recyclerview adapter class

```
public class Rvadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <Rvadapter.MyViewHolder> {

   private Context context;
   Activity activity;
    MyDatabaseHelper myDB;
    String questiontitle, question1, question2, question3, question4, question5, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer5;
    String answerdb1, answerdb2, answerdb3, answerdb4, answerdb5;
    Cursor cursor;
   ArrayList<ItemList> arlist;
   int marks, totalmark;
   private ArrayList arquestiontitle, arquestion1, arquestion2, arquestion3, arquestion4, arquestion5, aranswer1, aranswer2, aranswer3, aranswer4, aranswer5, armarks;
  String idtosee, orderid, orderdate, customername, customeraddress, customerphone, delifee, advance, tax, discount, itemname, itemcount, itemprice, mark;
    int a;
    Rvadapter(Activity activity, Context context, ArrayList arquestiontitle, ArrayList arquestion1, ArrayList arquestion2, ArrayList arquestion3, ArrayList arquestion4, ArrayList arquestion5, ArrayList aranswer1, ArrayList aranswer2, ArrayList aranswer3, ArrayList aranswer4, ArrayList aranswer5, ArrayList armarks){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = context;
       this.arquestiontitle = arquestiontitle;
       this.arquestion1 = arquestion1;
       this.arquestion2 = arquestion2;
       this.arquestion3 = arquestion3;
       this.arquestion4 = arquestion4;
       this.arquestion5 = arquestion5;
       this.aranswer1 = aranswer1;
       this.aranswer2 = aranswer2;
       this.aranswer3 = aranswer3;
       this.aranswer4 = aranswer4;
       this.aranswer5 = aranswer5;
       this.armarks = armarks;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      View view =   inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardlayoutquestion, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.tvquestiontitle.setText(String.valueOf(arquestiontitle.get(position)));
        holder.tvquestion1.setText(String.valueOf(arquestion1.get(position)));
        holder.tvquestion2.setText(String.valueOf(arquestion2.get(position)));
        holder.tvquestion3.setText(String.valueOf(arquestion3.get(position)));
        holder.tvquestion4.setText(String.valueOf(arquestion4.get(position)));
        holder.tvquestion5.setText(String.valueOf(arquestion5.get(position)));
        holder.tvquestionid.setText(String.valueOf(position+1+". "));
        marks = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(armarks.get(position)));
        answerdb1 = String.valueOf(aranswer1.get(position));
        answerdb2 = String.valueOf(aranswer2.get(position));
        answerdb3 = String.valueOf(aranswer3.get(position));
        answerdb4 = String.valueOf(aranswer4.get(position));
        answerdb5 = String.valueOf(aranswer5.get(position));


        holder.bta1true.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(answer1 == null){
                    answer1 = "T";
                    holder.bta1true.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected120);
                    holder.bta1false.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unselected120);
                }else if ( answer1.equals("F")){
                    answer1 = "T";
                    holder.bta1true.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected120);
                    holder.bta1false.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unselected120);
                }else {
                    answer1 = null;
                    holder.bta1true.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unselected120);
                }
            }
        });
        
        holder.bta1false.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(answer1 == null){
                    answer1 = "F";
                    holder.bta1false.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected120);
                    holder.bta1true.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unselected120);
                }else if ( answer1.equals("T")){
                    answer1 = "F";
                    holder.bta1true.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unselected120);
                    holder.bta1false.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected120);
                }else {
                    answer1 = null;
                    holder.bta1false.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unselected120);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void checkmarks() {
        if(answer1!=null){
            if(answer1.equals(answerdb1)){
                marks++;
            }else {
                marks--;
            }
        }

        if(answer2!=null){
            if(answer2.equals(answerdb2)){
                marks++;
            }else{
                marks--;
            }
        }

        if(answer3!=null){
            if(answer3.equals(answerdb3)){
                marks++;
            }else{
                marks--;
            }
        }

        if(answer4!=null){
            if(answer4.equals(answerdb4)){
                marks++;
            }else{
                marks--;
            }
        }

        if(answer5!=null){
            if(answer5.equals(answerdb5)){
                marks++;
            }else{
                marks--;
            }
        }

        if(marks<0){
            marks=0;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arquestiontitle.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvquestiontitle, tvquestion1, tvquestion2, tvquestion3, tvquestion4, tvquestion5, tvquestionid, tvmarks;
        Button bta1true, bta1false, bta2true, bta2false, bta3true, bta3false, bta4true, bta4false, bta5true, bta5false;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvquestiontitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvquestiontitle);
            tvquestion1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvquestion1);
            tvquestion2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvquestion2);
            tvquestion3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvquestion3);
            tvquestion4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvquestion4);
            tvquestion5 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvquestion5);
            tvquestionid = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvquestionid);
            tvmarks = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvmarks);
            bta1true = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bta1true);
            bta1false = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bta1false);
            bta2true = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bta2true);
            bta2false = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bta2false);
            bta3true = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bta3true);
            bta3false = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bta3false);
            bta4true = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bta4true);
            bta4false = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bta4false);
            bta5true = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bta5true);
            bta5false = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bta5false);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me... how to calculate marks of each question (recycler cardview items) and Sum together all of those.. I can manage to get them with only one question at a time with next button, but this time i want to show all questions within the recyclerview..

Comment: i forgot to say that i have 3answer options: True, False & not answer. If user's answer is right- mark add +1, if user answer is wrong-mark subtact -1, if user not answer- no need to add or subtract mark.. There fore if the user click 3right answer and 2wrong answer, the total marks for that question should be "1". And i also want to use buttons for that userInterface like that shown in the image in the question... please..sir.. i am making an app for my medical university..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use checkboxes instead

First of all. If the user inputs (answers in this case) are Boolean type then you should use [checkboxes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox) instead of buttons (much easier to deal with).
The layout will looks something like that:
[image]
You can stick with buttons if you want

### Create a class to store answers

Then make a class to store answers in it (let call it `Answer`)

```
public class Answer {

    private int questionNumber;//number of the question
    private Boolean bta1, bta2, bta3, bta4, bta5;//answers
    public Answer() {
    }

    public Answer(int questionNumber, Boolean bta1, Boolean bta2, Boolean bta3, Boolean bta4, Boolean bta5) {
        this.questionNumber = questionNumber;
        this.bta1 = bta1;
        this.bta2 = bta2;
        this.bta3 = bta3;
        this.bta4 = bta4;
        this.bta5 = bta5;
    }

    public int getQuestionNumber() {
        return questionNumber;
    }

    public void setQuestionNumber(int questionNumber) {
        this.questionNumber = questionNumber;
    }

    public Boolean getBta1() {
        return bta1;
    }

    public void setBta1(Boolean bta1) {
        this.bta1 = bta1;
    }

    public Boolean getBta2() {
        return bta2;
    }

    public void setBta2(Boolean bta2) {
        this.bta2 = bta2;
    }

    public Boolean getBta3() {
        return bta3;
    }

    public void setBta3(Boolean bta3) {
        this.bta3 = bta3;
    }

    public Boolean getBta4() {
        return bta4;
    }

    public void setBta4(Boolean bta4) {
        this.bta4 = bta4;
    }

    public Boolean getBta5() {
        return bta5;
    }

    public void setBta5(Boolean bta5) {
        this.bta5 = bta5;
    }

}
```

### Create an object for each question

and create object for each question in the MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ArrayList<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initializeAnswers();
        .
        .
        .
    }
    
    // here we create object for each question and make it default value all false
    public void initializeAnswers(){
        for (int i=1;i<=20;i++){//replace 20 with how many questions you have
            answers.add(new Answer(i,false,false,false,false,false));
        }
    }
    // this is the methode that will be called when the user press a checkbox(change its value)
    public void setQuestionResult(int questionNumber, int optionNumber, boolean value){
        switch (optionNumber){
            case 1:
                answers.get(questionNumber+1).setBta1(value);
                break;
            case 2:
                answers.get(questionNumber+1).setBta2(value);
                break;
            case 3:
                answers.get(questionNumber+1).setBta3(value);
                break;
            case 4:
                answers.get(questionNumber+1).setBta4(value);
                break;
            case 5:
                answers.get(questionNumber+1).setBta5(value);
                break;
        }
    }
    
}
```

### Catch user inputs

After that we gonna set click listener to each button(or checkbox) in the recyclerview items, so when the user chose an answer we store it in the objects we made before.
We'll do that in the `ViewHolder`

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    int questionNumber;
    TextView tvquestiontitle, tvquestion1, tvquestion2, tvquestion3, tvquestion4, tvquestion5, tvquestionid, tvmarks;
    CheckBox bta1, bta2, bta3, bta4, bta5;
    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvquestiontitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvquestiontitle);
        tvquestion1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvquestion1);
        tvquestion2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvquestion2);
        tvquestion3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvquestion3);
        tvquestion4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvquestion4);
        tvquestion5 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvquestion5);
        tvquestionid = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvquestionid);
        tvmarks = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvmarks);
        bta1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bta1);
        bta2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bta2);
        bta3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bta3);
        bta4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bta4);
        bta5 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bta5);
        View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Is the view now checked?
                boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
                int optionNumber;// e.g "1 is A" "2 is B" etc..
                //get option number form the view id
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.bta1:
                        optionNumber = 1;
                        break;
                    case R.id.bta2:
                        optionNumber = 2;
                        break;
                    case R.id.bta3:
                        optionNumber = 3;
                        break;
                    case R.id.bta4:
                        optionNumber = 4;
                        break;
                    case R.id.bta5:
                        optionNumber = 5;
                        break;
                    default:
                        optionNumber = 0;
                }
                // here we will pass the changes to setQuestionResult to the Activity to process it
                ((MainActivity)context).setQuestionResult(questionNumber,optionNumber,checked);
            }
        };
        bta1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bta2.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bta3.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bta4.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        bta5.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    }
}
```

You may realize that I added an parameter in the top (`int questionNumber;`), that's gonna identify what question we're dealing with.
You also need to set a value for this parameter in `onBindViewHolder`.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.questionNumber = position+1;//add one because the position of the first item is 0
    .
    .
    .
}
```

### Calculate marks of each question

Finally. when you want calculate marks of a question, the result is stored in `answers` to get it just call

```
answers.get(questioNumber+1)//add one because the index always start from 0
```

One Last thing. You may face a problem when changing the state of an item in recyclerview, so when you scroll down the first items became invisible and the recyclerview **recycle** those items, so any changes happened (e. g checking a checkbox) will be lost, and the items will reset to the first state.
If that happened check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50328655/recyclerview-items-values-reset-when-scrolling-down)

## Update

As I mentioned before, you can still do it with buttons if you want or any input type you find it better
The only thing you need to change is the way of catching user inputs.
E.g. if you used buttons, you'll have 3 possible inputs:

1. True. If btn1 is pressed and btn2 is not
2. False. If btn1 in bot pressed bur btn2 in pressed
3. Neither. If btn1 and btn2 are not pressed

You can sill use Boolean type to store the input by putting `null` when the value is *Neither true of false*(e.g. `bta1=null`)

The problem with this method is that it's pretty complicated and confusing (but still possible)
So. My suggestion is to use 3 statues checkbox.
This is a third-party library witch you can add to your preject.
It's pretty much a checkbox with three stats

1. Checked
2. Unchecked
3. Indeterminate

You can find it here [GitHub](https://github.com/sephiroth74/Tri-State-Checkbox)
And another one here [GitHub](https://github.com/sevar83/indeterminate-checkbox)

Comment: Sir... First dev.. your answer is perfect.. but i forgot to say that i have 3answer options: True, False & not answer. If user's answer is right- mark add +1, if user answer is wrong-mark subtact -1, if user not answer- no need to add or subtract mark.. There fore if the user click 3right answer and 2wrong answer, the total marks for that question should be "1". And i also want to use buttons for that userInterface like that shown in the image in the question... please..sir.. i am making an app for my medical university...

Comment: @John, As I said you can still use buttons you just need to change the way to catch the input. Check my answer again(updated) for more information.

Comment: Sir finally I got it by using buttons. I've changed the setQuestionResult method to 5 answer variables, instead of one. Thanks a lot for your great help.